# Cannot disable SSL for JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jmx

I am following this JMX guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html). Under the `Disabling SSL` section it says that `com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false` JVM property can be set to disable SSL for JMX.

I am testing this on tomcat server. I edit the tomcat startup script `catalina.sh` and add this property.

This property is used by tomcat during startup:
[image]

Then I connect to `tomcat` using `jconsole`
[image]

It still tries to connect via SSL:
[image]

I've also tried this with Active MQ, SOAP UI etc with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on insecure. Jconsole complains there is no SSL and just warn you about that.

Comment: I think jconsole tries to make a SSL connection and fails (due to missing certificate or something) and then gives option to connect insecurely. The option I think has no effect as making it true or false has jconsole behave the same.

Comment: jconsole can't know that you disable SSL on tomcat. So it start using  it first. It fails and allows you to continue without it with the insecure button. As you started tomcat without SSL, that's exactly what you asked for. If you set ssl to true, that will not be enough, SSL is something complicated to set up.